# Prevent the inside div from inheriting

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one DIV inside another and I want to prevent the inside div from inheriting the cursor css from the container DIV. And prevent the jQuery click functionality on the inside DIV.

```
<div id="page_wrapper">

    <div id="content_wrapper">
        Lorum Ipsum<br />
        Lorum Ipsum<br />
        Lorum Ipsum
    </div> 

</div>
```

CSS

```
#page_wrapper {
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#content_wrapper {
    z-index:20;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
}
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$("#page_wrapper").click(function() {
       alert("Clicked!");
});
</script>
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/digisol/eUpXk/

Comment: in your css for content_wrapper, just add `cursor: default;` to set the cursor back to a normal one when hovering over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#content_wrapper").css('cursor', 'default').click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BKkSj/11/)

Comment: No need to add new event listener for OP's purpose

Comment: This also doesn't address the CSS part of the question.

Comment: I have addressed that in the demo. Have a look once.

Comment: better would be to set css property in css not jquery

Comment: Yes, we can do it in both ways. I have just shown the OP the jQuery option.

Comment: Ok this is great but how would you do it using just CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Make these two changes:

**jQuery:**

```
$("#page_wrapper").click(function(e) {
       if(e.target === this) alert("Clicked!");
});
```

**CSS**

```
#content_wrapper {
    z-index:20;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    cursor: default; /* NEW */
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BKkSj/12/)**

Comment: if(e.target === this) seems more elegant